# How to get the number of days of the current month?

Tags: php, date

I want to check if today is the last day of the month, but I don't really know how.

Can you help?

Comment: I came here to understand how to get the number of days of the current month (< if you are interested in it, read about the [cal_days_in_month](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_cal_cal_days_in_month.asp) function). The title should be something like "PHP: How to check if today is the last day of the current month?"

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There is probably a more elegant solution than this but you can just use php's date function:

```
$maxDays=date('t');
$currentDayOfMonth=date('j');

if($maxDays == $currentDayOfMonth){
  //Last day of month
}else{
  //Not last day of the month
}
```

Comment: The `time()` calls are redundant since the current timestamp is what's used by default. Not that it matters though :)

Answer (score 42):

Try to use this:

```
date('t');
```

Answer (score 17):

**date('t');**

or you may use

**cal_days_in_month.**

see here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php

Comment: cal_days_in_month is better method, you can give any specific month and year for it

Answer (score 15):

In order to get no. of days in month
you can use either

```
date('t')
```

OR

```
cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 8, 2003)
```

And if you wish to check if today is the last day of month
us can use

```
if(date('d')==date('d',strtotime('last day of month'))){
//your code
}
```

strtotime offers many great features so check them out first

Answer (score 6):

Use php's function: cal_days_in_month

More details [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php)

```
cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 8, 2003);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function:

```
if (date('t') == date('j'))
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$date = new DateTime('last day of this month');
$numDaysOfCurrentMonth = $date->format('d');
```

Answer (score 4):

this is to find the days in any month:

```
$days = intval(date('t', strtotime($desiredDate)));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
     echo date('t'); /// it return last date of current month
```

Answer (score 0):

And here it is, wrapped up as a function:

```
function is_last_day_of_month($timestamp = NULL) {
    if(is_null($timestamp))
        $timestamp = time();
    return date('t', $timestamp) == date('j', $timestamp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the modern DateTime object class:

```
$date = new DateTime('last day of this month');
```

Answer (score 0):

With DateTime ;)

```
    $date = new \DateTime('now');
    var_dump($date->format('t'));
```