# PHP iterate days of month given month and year

Tags: php, date, parameters

How can I print (echo) the days of an unknown month if month and year are parameters?

Thank you.

Comment: unknown month if month : part is not clear. Are you looking for a way to find number of days in a given mm/yyyy ?

Comment: Yup, I want to know how many days it has so I can run a for and show them from 1 to max_days_in_that_month.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get the number of days of the current month? in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691142/how-to-get-the-number-of-days-of-the-current-month-in-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the number of days in a given month of a given year you can use [`cal_days_in_month`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php)

```
echo cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 10, 2010); // prints 31
```

Comment: Haha, brilliant. Thank you. I need this to improvise a special kind of calendar that only shows some days etc.

Comment: PHP really has a function for everything, doesn't it? i would have suggested using the date function and using the days-in-month format char... but this is easier.

Comment: Yeah, it seems it does, haha.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the date() function to get the number of days in a month. You can also pass the 2nd param strtotime() and specify a specific date:

```
$daysInMon = date('t', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month));
```