# Calculate number of days in each month for a given year using PHP

Tags: php, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP iterate days of month given month and year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883788/php-iterate-days-of-month-given-month-and-year)

How can I calculate number of days in each month for a given year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this I created a function as below:

```
// Calculate number of days in each month for a given year.
function getDays($year){

    $num_of_days = array();
    $total_month = 12;
    if($year == date('Y'))
        $total_month = date('m');
    else
        $total_month = 12;

    for($m=1; $m<=$total_month; $m++){
        $num_of_days[$m] = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $m, $year);
    }

    return $num_of_days;
}
$num_of_days = getDays('2011');
print_r($num_of_days);
```

Answer (score 2):

read this [cal_days_in_month](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php)

> Return the number of days in a month for a given year and calendar

Comment: note: i am unable to write `cal_days_in_month()` in codeblock??? why!!!!

Comment: beat me by 50 sec.... +1 for the speed

Comment: use ` inside the [] like [`cal_days_in_mmonth`].

Comment: i did Buddy... actually there is some problem in `chrome`. i m unable to see any code block now :( need to check

Comment: This function is a plugin to PHP