# Obtain a month is a few days?

Tags: php, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP iterate days of month given month and year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883788/php-iterate-days-of-month-given-month-and-year)

"Obtain all days in month with the number of months"

For example i have date `2011/12/16` this date have months `12`(december) now i want with code php know that, This month(12 or december) is a few days?(29? or 31? or 30?)

How is it by PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mydate = strtotime('2011/12/16');
$daysInMonth = date('t',$mydate);
```

Edited to add strtotime()

Comment: @Kate - $mydate does need to be a valid date/time value... not a string. Use strtotime() to get a date/time value from '2011/12/16'