# Get date difference from looped dates in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have found this on internet but i have no idea to fix this.

```
$dt = new DateTime(date('Y-m-31'));
$n_mon = 7;

echo $dt->format('Y-m-d').'<br>';

for ($i=0; $i < $n_mon; $i++) { 

  $day = $dt->format('j');
  $dt->modify('first day of +1 month');
  $dt->modify('+' . (min($day, $dt->format('t')) - 1) . ' days');

  echo $dt->format('Y-m-d').'<br>';
  // code...
}
```

Outputs
2023-01-31
2023-02-28
2023-03-28
2023-04-28
2023-05-28
2023-06-28
2023-07-28
2023-08-28

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So all you need is the number of days in a month?

Comment: [How to get the number of days of the current month?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3691142)

Answer (score 0):

you can try get days in month like this

```
<?php
$n_months = 14;
$date  = new DateTime("2022-01-01");
for ($i = 1; $i <= $n_months; $i++) {
    $thisM = $date->format("M");
    $thisY = $date->format("Y");
    $days  = $date->format("t");
    $date->modify("+1 month");
    $nextM = $date->format("M");
    $nextY = $date->format("Y");
    echo "{$thisM} {$thisY} - {$nextM} {$nextY} = {$days}\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: This very useful, but when the $n_months = 14: it will give me this error: Message: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2022-13-1) at position 6 (3): Unexpected character

Comment: @mopacs13 i have changed my post, try that